# jquery animate jerky - is there a better library for scaling images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I noticed whenever I use jquery animate with long time and small change animation becomes incredibly jerky! The only way to fix this seems to decrease time considerably and scale more. But in some projects this is not possible...

I looked into css transitions. And it didn't provide better results. Animation itself was better, but firefox was horridly jerky and in chrome animation finishes were not quite there with smoothness.

So my question is this, is there any other library with animation engine that can provide smooth scaling of images? or is there a technique that I'm missing?

This is my animation:

```
$('.item a').mouseover(function(){
    //
        var this_img = $(this).find('.img_grayscale');
        var css_w = parseInt(this_img.attr("width"), 10);
        var css_h = parseInt(this_img.attr("height"), 10);
        // 10% of height and width calc here
        var css_p_w = css_w * 10 / 100;
        var css_p_h = css_h * 10 / 100;
        // 
        var css_top = -(css_p_h / 2);
        var css_left = -(css_p_w / 2);
    //
    this_img.stop().animate({ opacity:1 }, 100, function(){
        this_img.animate({width:css_w + css_p_w, height:css_h + css_p_h, top:css_top, left:css_left}, 1200, "linear");
    });
    //this_img.transitionStop().transition({ opacity:1 }, 100, function(){
    //  this_img.transition({ scale:1.05, rotate:0.02 }, 2500, "ease");
    //});
    //
}).mouseout(function(){
    //
        var this_img = $(this).find('.img_grayscale');
        var css_w = parseInt(this_img.attr("width"), 10);
        var css_h = parseInt(this_img.attr("height"), 10);
    //
    this_img.stop().animate({ width:css_w, height:css_h, top:"0", left:"0" }, 1200, "linear", function(){
        this_img.animate({ opacity:0 }, 100);
    });
    //this_img.transitionStop().transition({ scale:1 }, 2500, "ease", function(){
    //  this_img.transition({ opacity:0, rotate:0.02 }, 100)
    //});
    //
});
```

Commented out parts are jquery.transit plugin tests, this plugin provides css3 transitions.

Live example: http://mac.idev.ge:800/test/ (hover images)

Comment: I'd really really really recommend the greensock tweening libraries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the smoothest look and best performance I would definately recommend using css scale transform.

There's some gotchas to be aware of though. It seems some browsers try to be clever and optimizes transforms which only results in a size change in the image. The trick is to also apply a small rotation:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) rotate(0.1deg);
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) rotate(0.1deg);
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g2Qrv/

It scales smoothly in Chrome, FF, IE10, Opera and Safari on iOS.

Comment: Do you have any experience with background transitions? I noticed on some websites they use this technique instead of working directly on images.

Comment: Do you mean using the background-size property? It isn't as smooth in my experience. It's similar to just animating the widht/height properties of an image.

Comment: yep just tested it, and it is even worth than jquery animate() :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use simple CSS transitions, here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/XgewX/).

```
<img src="some-image.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
img:hover {
    width: 440px;
    height: 330px;
    top: 85px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Do you see how jerky animation is when I change 0.2s to 1s? http://jsfiddle.net/XgewX/1/

Comment: Why would you use 1s for animations? Users don't go to your site to see animations, it has to be minimal.

Comment: if I want slow animation? "Users don't go to your site to see animations, it has to be minimal." exactly slow animations are less intrusive to the eye.